# How to add the zoom controls to the Mapwidget using Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I can't find the way to add the zoom controls to the MapWidget using google maps.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drone_view);

    mapWidget = findViewById(R.id.map_widget);
    mapWidget.initGoogleMap(new MapWidget.OnMapReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull DJIMap djiMap) {
            cameraUpdate();
            djiMap.setOnMapClickListener(new DJIMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(DJILatLng djiLatLng) {
                    onViewClick(mapWidget);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    mapWidget.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapWidget.getMap().getUiSettings().a(true);
    // shows "a(boolean)" to the "h(boolean)" methods
 }
```

When i run the app i get the next error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.dji.mapkit.maps.c com.dji.mapkit.maps.DJIMap.getUiSettings()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to modify the map before it has finished initializing. Call `djiMap.getUiSettings()` inside the `onMapReady()` method instead.